# Can I open a file in an existing Vim instance from an external command?

Tags: sessions, clientserver, invocation

Some applications have the notion of a *"session"*, where you can run a command to load a file in an existing instance of an application.

For example, when I type:

```
$ firefox http://vi.stackexchange.com
```

Firefox re-uses an existing Firefox process, rather than creating a new one.

Is this possible with Vim?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need vim compiled with `+clientserver`, and then you can use the command:

`vim --servername SERVER` to start a vim instance, and

`vim --servername SERVER --remote FILE` to open the file in the named vim instance.

---

#### macOS only

MacVim runs a server by default - you can use

`mvim --remote-tab-silent` to open a file in a new tab in your existing MacVim instance, or

`mvim --remote-silent` to open the file in a new buffer in the same tab.

Comment: if you want this in NeoVim, which doesn't support --servername, install [Neovim-Remote](https://github.com/mhinz/neovim-remote) by doing `pip3 install neovim-remote` and then you can do `nvr --remote filename.txt` from a seperate shell to open filename in the other, or use `nvr -l filename.txt` from a `:terminal` buffer inside vim, to open the file in the other buffer (rather than opening vim within vim, as you otherwise might). Similarly, git can be configured to use the vim instance calling it, rather than spawning vim within vim.

Comment: I wish there was a way to get this to work with `open -g -a /Applications/MacVim.app --args --remote-silent file1.txt file2.txt` bit. I end up getting separate windows for each file.

Answer (score 7):

While @craigp's answer is correct, I found it most convenient to simply add `--remote-silent` without worrying about server names,
*(this assumes you don't want to address named vim instances)*.

This will start the server, or use one if its not already started.

It can be called like this:

```
gvim --remote-silent '+cal cursor(line,col)' some_file
```

eg:

```
gvim --remote-silent '+cal cursor(102,4)' src/code.c
```

I ended up needing to use a different method of moving the cursor because of this remote initialization.

Comment: I tried doing this, but I only ended up with a new instance of vim each time I ran vim --remote-silent <file>. I am running neovim, if that has something to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @craigp's answer, you can also open a file in a remote tab.

`vim --servername SERVER --remote-tab FILE`

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!