# Is there a way to make a command running inside a vim terminal open files in buffers?

Tags: terminal

I often find myself operating in the vim terminal needing to edit a few files. In this case I might type `vim *.h`. This opens a new vim instance nested inside my vim terminal. Is there a way to make a command that instead triggers the parent vim instance to load the files in buffers?

Comment: I suppose you mean `:args *.h`

Comment: If I understand your question properly, it is a duplicate of [this one](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/317/1841): Start vim with `vim --servername SERVER` and from within the terminal buffer use `vim --servername SERVER --remote *.h`. However I think your workflow could be improved: you don't need to open a terminal to open new files, instead you could use builtin commands like [`:h :args`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Aargs) or [`:h :argadd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Aargadd) or even a fuzzy finder like [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim)

Comment: If you're using `neovim`, https://github.com/mhinz/neovim-remote does what you want. Other options are covered in question linked by @statox.

Comment: @statox - I think the example I chose is too simplified. I often want to use complex pipes of greps to make a file list. For example `vim $( ... something ... )`. Which I can do easily, but I would like it not create a session nested inside the terminal, and instead pop up a series of buffers.

Answer (score 4):

I found it more intuitive (YMMV!) to create a bash script called `:e`, containing this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f; do
    echo -e "\033]51;[\"drop\", \"$f\"]\007"
done
```

So `:e file` works both at the vim command line, as well as in a terminal-within-vim

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using the [:terminal](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#terminal) mode in vim 8.
My answer is a modification of [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/21813/21403) answer.

1. Create a special function in your vimrc that's callable from terminal, its name must start with `Tapi_`.

```
function! Tapi_vit(bufnum, arglist)
   let currfile = get(a:arglist, 0, '')
   if empty(currfile)
     return
   endif
   execute 'e' currfile
endfunction
```

2. Create a function and then an alias in your .zshrc or .bashrc.
   If you are in vim's terminal, then the file(s) would be opened in current vim. Works with wildcards(*) too.

```
 vit()
 {
   if [[ ! -z "$VIM_TERMINAL" ]]; then
     if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
       echo "You are already inside Vim. Provide filenames as arguments"
     else
       readlink -f $@ | xargs printf '\033]51;["call", "Tapi_vit", ["%s"]]\007'
     fi
   else
     vim $@
   fi
 }
alias vim=vit
```

The leading \033]51; and the trailing \007 are special escape sequence recognized by vim.
check [:h terminal-api](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#terminal-api) for more detail.

Series of actions.

- vim
- :terminal
- Go to desired directory in :terminal buffer
- vim *.h in the :terminal buffer. All *.h will open in current vim instance.
- Just vim without arguments in the :terminal buffer will give the message "You are already inside Vim. Provide filenames as arguments"
- If you are in a normal terminal, its as usual vim (a new vim instance is started)

**I use Cygwin on Windows. So, this works there as well. I probably have to write a different version if you need it working with 'cmd' on windows. I will update this answer if I manage to do that.**

Hope it helps.