# how to change local directory of terminal buffer whenever its shell change directory

Tags: terminal

After `:term ++curwin zsh`, I use that buffer as an alternative of tmux window.

But there is one caveat, if I `cd` in zsh, vim will not know.

Which cause problem in below case

In terminal normal mode, `gf` will not work correctly, since vim don't know zsh has changed directory.

After googling, I found [zsh support hook for directory change](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171764/how-can-i-run-a-command-in-bash-after-any-change-in-pwd).

The problem is, my vim & shell expertise is insufficient to use that hook to tell vim change local directory of corresponding terminal buffer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Create a special function in your vimrc that's callable from terminal, its name must start with `Tapi_`.

```
" arglist : [ cwd ]
" change window local working directory
function! Tapi_lcd(bufnum, arglist)
  let winid = bufwinid(a:bufnum)
  let cwd = get(a:arglist, 0, '')
  if winid == -1 || empty(cwd)
    return
  endif
  call win_execute(winid, 'lcd ' . cwd)
endfunction
```

2. create a function in your zshrc to call `Tapi_lcd` in terminal:

```
cdv()
{
  printf '\033]51;["call", "Tapi_lcd", ["%s"]]\007' "$(pwd)"
}
```

The leading `\033]51;` and the trailing `\007` are special escape sequence recognized by vim.

check [:h terminal-api](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#terminal-api) for more detail.

You can now use `cdv` in terminal to change window local directory now (personally I would stop here, it's good enough for me).

3. hook `cd` and `cdv`

```
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook -Uz chpwd cdv
```

Now they are `hooked`, `cdv` is called every time you `cd` .
There are some side effect you should know, as some subshell environment (such as `$()`) is a duplicate of the current shell environment, the hook works in such subshell too. For example:

```
( cd / )
```

Above command will trigger `cdv`, it change your working directory to `/`, if you want to avoid that, you need to filter out subshell `cd`:

```
cdv()
{
  if [[ $ZSH_SUBSHELL -eq 0 ]] ; then
    printf '\033]51;["call", "Tapi_lcd", ["%s"]]\007' "$(pwd)"
  fi
}
```

I'm not a shell veteran, the hook make me nervous, <s>I wouldn't use it</s>,.

**update for nvim**

```
" in init.vim/vimrc
fu Tapi_lcd(buf, cwd) abort
    if has('nvim')
        exe 'lcd '..a:cwd
        return ''
    endif
    let winid = bufwinid(a:buf)
    if winid == -1 || empty(a:cwd)
        return
    endif
    call win_execute(winid, 'lcd '..a:cwd)
endfu

# in zshrc
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
if [[ -n "$VIM_TERMINAL" ]]; then
  add-zsh-hook -Uz chpwd cdv
  cdv() {
    printf -- '\033]51;["call", "Tapi_lcd", "%q"]\007' "$(pwd)"
  }
elif [[ -n "$NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS" ]]; then
  add-zsh-hook -Uz chpwd cdv
  cdv() {
    nvr --servername "$VIM_SERVERNAME" --remote-expr "$(printf -- 'Tapi_lcd(0, "%q")' "$(pwd)")"
  }
fi
```

It requires the `nvr` command; you can get it [from here](https://github.com/mhinz/neovim-remote), or by running this shell command:

```
python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade neovim-remote
```

**update for bash**

There is no `hook` in bash, but we can use an alias and a function to hook cd and cdv. After step 2, put this in your `bashrc`:

```
cdv()
{
  printf '\033]51;["call", "Tapi_lcd", ["%s"]]\007' "$(pwd)"
}

cd_and_cdv()
{
  'cd' "$@" && cdv
}

hookvim()
{
    alias cd=cd_and_cdv
}
```

execute `hookvim` after entering `terminal`, done. This solution works for `zsh` too.

**update: set up hook automatically**

[:h terminal-unix](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#terminal-unix) add a bunch of environment variable to terminal inside vim, we can use it to setup hook.

Put this to you zshrc/bashrc :

```
if [[ ! -z "$VIM_TERMINAL" ]]; then
   hookvim
fi
```

Comment: Wouldn't work in bash, right?

Comment: @eyalkarni See update.

Comment: you could also hook into $PROMPT_COMMAND

Comment: fantasy! Never thought it could be so simple.

Comment: Didn't work for me in neoterm. cdv does nothing.

Comment: @eyalkarni It's for vim8, `neovim` has different terminal api.

Answer (score 1):

A slight adaptation of @dedowsdi answer for neoterm. This plugin https://github.com/kassio/neoterm that provides improved terminal.

you can use this in the bash_profile

```
if [[ ! -z "$NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS" ]]; then
hookvim
fi
```

But I don't. Because in the code I assume that the terminal is in an opened tab to the right (switch to the window and back). one can upgrade the code a bit to avoid this. Notice that you also need to have neovim-remote for this to work.

```
cdv()
{
  #printf '\033]51;["call", "Tapi_lcd", ["%s"]]\007' "$(pwd)"
  nvr --servername $NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS --remote-send '<c-\><c-N><c-w>h:lcd '"$(pwd)"'<CR><c-w>li'
}

cd_and_cdv()
{
  cd "$@" && cdv
}

hookvim()
{
alias cd=cd_and_cdv
}
```

I open the terminal with (the argument is 0 for this to work)

```
set splitright
function! TermOV(use_file_dir)    
    let k=g:neoterm.last_id+1
    vertical Tnew
    exe k."T . /etc/bashrc"
    exe k."T . ~/.bash_profile"
    if a:use_file_dir
        exe k."T cd " . expand('%:p:h')
    else
        exe k."T hookvim" 
    endif  

    exe k."Tclear"
endfunction
```

Comment: Are those T commands from a plugin or custom?

Comment: These are neoterm commands https://github.com/kassio/neoterm

Comment: Might want to mention that, then, since it isnt copy-paste-able without that plugin

Comment: I did but will stress it.

Comment: why do you use `splitright`?

Comment: I like it more to the right. Actually, that is the default in my .vimrc

Comment: But maybe you mean, why is it required here. Because I go to the window to the left, do `lcd` and then go back.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin could be halpful with given cases: https://github.com/skywind3000/vim-terminal-help

Following settings allow to open current terminal dir in vim in one key:

```
let g:terminal_edit="edit"
tmap <F6> drop .<CR>
```